# Как сделать вывод всех данных таблицы в одном сообщении

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Хочу вывести данные 2х таблиц в формате

```
q:
a:
q:
a:
```

и тд

```
cursor = connect.cursor()
i = 0
while i<6:
 i=i+1
 Q = cursor.execute("SELECT question.Text FROM question WHERE ID < 6")
 A = cursor.execute("SELECT answers.Text FROM answers WHERE ID < 6")
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, Q, reply_markup = markup)
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, A, reply_markup = markup)
 connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное где-то так...

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{Q}: {A}", reply_markup = markup)
```

UPD.
Не это не совсем то что вам нужно.
Думаю вот так будет лучше.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT question.Text FROM question WHERE ID < 6")
Q = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT answers.Text FROM answers WHERE ID < 6")
A = cursor.fetchall()
connect.close()
message_str = ""
i = 0
while i < min(len(A), len(Q)):
    message_str += f"Q: {Q[i]}\nA: {A[i]}\n\n"
    i += 1 
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_str, reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'chat' пишет такую ошибку в этой строчке bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message, reply_markup = markup)

Comment: Обновил, проверяй

Comment: в телеге выходит не текст а вот это <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000021509F395C0>
и так еще 3 раза

Comment: Снова обновил, глянь что теперь выдает.

Comment: Так, теперь он выдал все строки Текст из двух таблиц, но это повторяется много раз. Получается строчка с циклом while это для сохранения всего в одном сообщении

Comment: Снова проверяй, по идее мы приближаемся

Comment: message_str += f"{Q[i]}: {A[i]}\n"
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: И снова проверка

Comment: Супер! оно выводит как надо! Как можно теперь это все отредактировать что бы текст выглядит красиво. типа Q: (Вопрос) \n A: (Ответ) \n\n и тд

Comment: Глянь комм выше, пожалуйста. я его чутка подредачил

Comment: Кинь текстом как конкретно сейчас выводит

Comment: ('Будут ли выходить обновления так же на смартфоны?',): ('Да, обновления будут так же выходит и на телефон.',) Ответы выходят в таком формате просто

Comment: Снова обновил, проверяй

Comment: Работает! Ты лучший! СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!

Comment: Пожалуйста, удачи